# Неправильная ориентация .JPG в браузере

Tags: html, jpeg

Проблема: обнаружено, что картинки в формате .JPG (именно прописными буквами, с обычным .jpg - всё в порядке) в браузере меняют свою ориентацию.

```
<img src="какая-то-картинка.JPG"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vzLgay5a/1/

То есть одна картинка может быть отражена по вертикали, а другая повёрнута на 90°. Чем и как в таком случае повернуть её в ту ориентацию, в какой она отображается локально на машине.

Был бы также признателен, если кто-нибудь объяснил бы, почему вообще это происходит.

Comment: Это во всех браузерах или только в каком-то одном?

Comment: Наверняка в EXIF картинок записан поворт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в EXIF.

При просмотре в теле страницы показывает перевернутой, а при "открыть картинку в новой вкладке" показывает картинку повернутой правильно. Т.е. современные браузеры когда показывают только картинку берут ее (в моем случае повернутую набок) смотрят на EXIF и поворачивают как надо.

Первый вариант - при загрузке фото удалять все данные EXIF
Второй вариант - при загрузке фото если есть данные EXIF - повернуть фото согласно данных.

2 вариант

```
$img = new Imagick($uploaded_img);
$orientation = $img->getImageOrientation();
switch($orientation) { 
        case imagick::ORIENTATION_BOTTOMRIGHT: 
                $img->rotateimage("#000", 180); // rotate 180 degrees 
        break; 
        case imagick::ORIENTATION_RIGHTTOP: 
                $img->rotateimage("#000", 90); // rotate 90 degrees CW 
        break; 
        case imagick::ORIENTATION_LEFTBOTTOM: 
                $img->rotateimage("#000", -90); // rotate 90 degrees CCW 
        break; 
}
$img->setImageOrientation(imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);
$img->writeImage($uploaded_img);
$img->clear();
$img->destroy();
```

Первый вариант был бы примерно так:

```
$img = new Imagick($uploaded_img);
$img->stripImage();
$img->writeImage($uploaded_img);
$img->clear();
$img->destroy();
```

https://toster.ru/q/267428

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ! Подозревал, что где-то хранятся метаданные о повороте :).

Comment: P.S. Не удалось получить ориентацию: getImageOrientation() возвращает 0; stripImage() не помогает в данной случае; exif_read_data выдаёт кое-что, но секция exif пуста, ориентация отсутствует. Такой сервис, однако, выдаёт нужную информацию http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi , а Photoshop пишет, что orientation лежит не в "exif", а в "tiff properties". Может дело в том, что эти снимки сделаны с Айпада и хранят информацию в каких-то других тегах? Или же я криво пользуюсь imagick. Я так понимаю, что он не требует установки на web-сервере, раз его методы, такие как, например, writeImage() работают.